# How about an HTTPS tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have an [http](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/http) tag.  How about we add an [https](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/https) tag.

Alternatively, we could use a [protocols](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protocols) and have several synonyms, but since each protocol serves a different purposes, I would prefer that we use separate tags for each protocol.

The current lack of an [https](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/https) tag came up when trying to tag this question: [Tool to determine if any HTTP bookmarks can be replaced with HTTPS equivalents (Firefox)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35754/tool-to-determine-if-any-http-bookmarks-can-be-replaced-with-https-equivalents)

Answer (score 2):

I am in favour of a tag for each different protocol, such as FTP, WebDAV, CMIS, etc.

But I would be in favour of a single tag http for both HTTP and HTTPS, and a single tag ftp for FTP, FTPS, SFTP.

Instead, when talking about the secure version, I would add the security tag.

Comment: Good ideas.  Let me give it some more thought.  Part of me agrees and part disagrees, so I'll either write down my thoughts in an answer, or change my mind after thinking about it some more.

Answer (score 2):

While I see the usefulness of those tags for the specific purpose, I doubt the overall usefulness (as opposed to cluttering our tags unnecessarily). Quoting [our help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags):

> You should always favor existing tags; **only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case** that your question *does* cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

(emphasis mine). I know there's room for interpretation. But a tag that's too rarely used doesn't make a good tag IMHO.

So, picking the list given in [Nicolas' answer](/a/2600/185) (which is far from being complete, note the "etc."), we should first consider how useful each tag would *really* be. Not just for the question at hand (linked to from the question body above), but in general. A possible approach to that could be skimming/keyword-searching existing questions whether any might need such.

In so far I agree with Nicolas: we shouldn't create "pairs" to distinguish between "secured or not". Nowadays it's usually clear that the secured variant is to be preferred. But preferences should be part of the question body – and the [security](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) tag be reserved for cases where it's "real important" (i.e. a core requirement).

**TL;DR:** Could we agree on

1. only one tag per tag (ahem, e.g. no pairs like `http` plus `https` – or in my experience we'd end up with tons of questions using both)
2. instead, declare preferences in the question body – plus use the [security](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) where it marks a "core requirement" (otherwise always interpret the question as "secured to be preferred")
3. first evaluate which tags are really useful (i.e. not wildly add tags for each protocol just because there's one question matching it)

?

Comment: Well articulated.  Let me ponder this some more.  I see it from a couple different angles, and I'm not completely sure what is best.